# Binding a List<MyObject> to a DataGrid? When I try I get a "TargetInvocationException"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I'm trying to bind a `List<MyObject>` to a DataGrid in WPF instead of using an array of `MyObject[]`. Whenever I try and do this I get an unhandled `TargetInvocationException`.

My Object:

```
public class Website
{
    public string WebsiteName { get; set; }
    public string WebsiteAddress { get; set; }
    private LoginCredentials Credentials { get; set; }

    public bool UniquePassword { get; set; } //If uses uses a unique password on this site
    public bool LoginToSite { get; set; }
    public bool UsesUsernameAndDomain { get; set; }

    public string GetUsername()
    {
        if(UsesUsernameAndDomain)
        {
            return Credentials.Username + "@" + Credentials.EmailDomain;
        }
        else
        {
            return Credentials.Username;
        }
    }

    public void SetUsername(string value)
    {
        Credentials.Username = value;
    }

    public void SetDomain(string value)
    {
        Credentials.EmailDomain = value;
    }
}
```

The ViewModel snippet:

```
    private List<Website> m_Websites;
    public List<Website> Websites
    {
        get { return m_Websites; }
        set { m_Websites = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Websites"); }
    }
```

XAML:

```
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                  DataContext="{Binding Websites}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  FontSize="14"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
```

When I try this with an array it functions as expected. I want to use a collection for the additional behavior that it comes packaged with. What am I doing wrong here?

Note: I am very new to WPF, and only recently puzzled my way though data binding, do not assume I know the ins and outs of WPF or it's paradigms.

Comment: Can you post the code which is working? I mean the ViewModel snippet?

Comment: For me it worked using  AutoGenerateColumns="True"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a pretty novice mistake. When binding to a List Property, I was not instantiating the private field of type List.

I was trying to bind to:

```
    private List<Website> m_Websites;
    public List<Website> Websites
    {
        get { return m_Websites; }
        set { m_Websites = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Websites"); }
    }
```

I needed to instantiate a new list:

```
    private List<Website> m_Websites = new List<Websites>();
```